# How to capture a manual sharing event on an Object?

Tags: sharing

If I want to send an email to an user whenever a record is shared with him, how can I do so? More specifically, on what event should the email be sent?

Comment: You can query the shared records .share records will have userOrGroupId with whom it is shared and also the recordId so all you have to do is use messaging.email to send to the respective users. :) [Click this link to start working](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such event that you can use. The Share tables do not support triggers. You would have to periodically query the table on a schedule for new shares since the last check, then send the appropriate emails.

Comment: By table, do you mean AccountShare?

Comment: I think all the Share tables would not support triggers, there is one for each object where manual sharing is enabled, e.g. AccountShare, MyCustomObject__Share, remember for custom objects it is a double underscore between the name and the 'Share'.